# Capacitance of two wires with a grounded wire between

Tags: capacitor, wire, capacitance, grounding

I have measured the capacitance between wires number, say, 1 and 3. With the wiree #2 just floating, the result was 390 pF. But after i have grounded the wiree #2, the capacitance was 220 pF. What is the reason of these results?
The cable is FFC few meters long, so the wires just run in parallel.

Comment: Do you really believe your question can be answered with the information you supplied.  Do you have a schematic? How are the wires related to each other?  Are there only capacitors involved or other components? etc., etc.

Comment: What is the physical arrangement of the wires? If wire 2 is partially shielding between 1 and 3 that would a sensible result.

Comment: What type of meter measured the capacitance? Ditto the above comments.

Comment: Folks, the physical arrangement of the wires was already specified in the question title, but the poster has now added an additional description of the cable.

Comment: The description of the wire arrangement is pretty ambiguous. Without some sort of diagram, and a rigorous definition of what "grounded" means here, I don't see how it can be answered.

Comment: Don't know, i've just connected the second wire to the "grounding" connector in the lab.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSWIf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see L2 is now directly grounded instead of beign grounded through C20. If you do your math you can calculate C20 from those 2 measurements. I will leave the rest of it for you to do, have fun.

P.S. This is the representation using concentrated elements, you can create \$\Pi\$ or \$T\$ equivalents and connect them in a cascade to have a better representation of the circuit.